# How can I create a custom view in outlook that searches shows emails in all folders that have been unresponded to in the past 3 hours?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sql

I currently have the following SQL line in the view filter to search for unresponded emails but need the remaining two pieces, can someone help?

Unresponded emails:

http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003 IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

Not know much about SQL lines, but I found another workaround using custom forms which should be helpful to your issue as well. Please check: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3547-outlook-find-filter-unanswered-messages.html

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.